# How to return values from controls in popup and add them to the main page?

Tags: xamarin

The main page has a button for adding new items. When the user presses it, a popup window appears.
[image]
I used this code for popup.xaml:

```
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MReport.popup01"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             Size="300,400">
    
    
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">
            <Label Text="From Time:" Padding="5,5,0,0" TextColor="Black"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
            <TimePicker HorizontalOptions="Center" Time="00:00" />
            <Label Text="To Time" Padding="5,5,0,0" TextColor="Black"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
            <TimePicker HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label Text="Your Activities:" Padding="5,5,0,0" TextColor="Black" />
            <Editor x:Name="editor_value" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" />
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Add" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Cancel" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</xct:Popup>
```

For popup.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MReport
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class popup01 : Popup
    {
        public popup01()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dismiss("Cancelled");
        }

        private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

For TabbedPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MReport.TabbedMainPage">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="New Report" IconImageSource="NewReport.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg">
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollView>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label x:Name="lbl01" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Add New Item" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </Grid>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Send Report" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Report History" IconImageSource="History.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg" />
    <ContentPage Title="Messages" IconImageSource="Message.png" BackgroundImageSource="blue_windows.jpg"/>

</TabbedPage>
```

For TabbedPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Extensions;

namespace MReport
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TabbedMainPage : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
    {
        public TabbedMainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
            On<Android>().SetIsSmoothScrollEnabled(false);
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.ShowPopup(new popup01());
        }
    }
}
```

I use CommunityToolKit for the popup.
The popup has two buttons. The ADD button will add the information entered in the popup to the main page.
I want the output to be like the image I've provided.
These frame boxes and their texts are added each time the user presses the add button in the popup. Those frame boxes are expanded based on the text volume inside them. What code should be written for the ADD button?
Please help me.

Comment: the XCT samples include a demo of returning a value from a popup

Comment: Can you please give me some codes to study? I couldn't find any related tutorial about my question. Thanks

Comment: See “ReturnResultPopup” in the sample

Comment: Is this webpage where the sample file exists? https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit

Comment: yes, under the "samples" folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowPopupAsync` can return a value to the caller

```
var result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
```

whatever parameter is passed to `Dismiss()` will be returned to the caller

Comment: I used this code in `TabbedMainPage`:  `private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(popup01);
            lbl01.Text = result.ToString();
        }`

Comment: and this code in popup:         `private async void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dismiss(editor_value.Text);
        }`

Comment: When I press the button in `TabbedMainPage`, application goes to break mode and says: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: obj'

Comment: where are you declaring and instantiating `popup01`?

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks