# How to make change in APP.xaml.cs code to pass a parameter from one page to another in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to pass a parameter from one page to another.
I used this code for one of the pages:

```
public TabbedMainPage(string parameter)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
    On<Android>().SetIsSmoothScrollEnabled(false);
    lbl01.Text = parameter;
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new TabbedMainPage();
}
```

The problem is that App.xaml.cs has error under `TabbedMainPage`.
I tried `MainPage = new TabbedMainPage(parameter);` but the problem still exists.
Please help me.

Comment: "has error" is not a helpful description of the problem.  What is the **specific error** you are getting?

Comment: and where is App getting the value for `parameter` from?

Comment: The error says: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'parameter' of 'TabbedMainPage.TabbedMainPage(string)' MReport C:\Users\FARDIN\source\repos\MReport\MReport\MReport\App.xaml.cs 13 Active

Comment: that's because the constructor has a required parameter that you are not providing a value for

Comment: The parameter is linked to an Editor

Comment: Can you please help me by providing the code?

Comment: App is passing this value to TabbedMainPage.  Where is App getting the value from?  The App class does not have any UI elements of its own.

Comment: `MainPage = new TabbedMainPage("some value goes here");`

Comment: It gets value from a popup window called "popup01". I tried this: `MainPage = new TabbedMainPage(new popup01());` but its has error.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this works.  And please stop saying "has error" - we should not have to prompt you every time to provide the specific error message.

Comment: When I use `TabbedMainPage(new popup01());` Error message is: cannot convert from MReport.popup01 to 'string'`

Comment: that is because your constructor expects a parameter of type `string` and you are passing a parameter of type `popup01`, whatever that is.  If you want to display a popup and get a value from it, you need to write code in the page to do that.  You cannot just pass a type to the page and expect it to magically display for you.

Comment: I think I need to use an initial value as an empty string "".

Comment: I have written this code for a button exists in popup window:         `private async void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedMainPage(editor_value.Text));
            Dismiss(editor_value.Text);
        }` but I cannot pass value to the label in the main page

Comment: which page displays the popup?

Comment: By pressing a button in TabbedMainPage, the popup appears. The popup window name is popup01

Comment: `TabbedMainPage` already exists, you do not need to pass a parameter to the constructor.  There is no need for your popup to call `Navigation.PushAsync` because that **page already exists**.  You just need to dismiss the popup to go back to `TabbedMainPage`.

Comment: I can go back to the `TabbedMainPage` using `Dismiss()` but I cannot pass Entry value from popup tp the label in `TabbedMainPage`

Comment: I deleted all those codes and just kept `Dismiss()`. Please help me. If you give me the code that does what I mean, I can learn better.

Comment: yes you can.  I pointed this out to you **TWO DAYS AGO**.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144042/how-to-return-values-from-controls-in-popup-and-add-them-to-the-main-page

Comment: I downloaded those sample files. but they don't work in my Visual Studio 2019. It is full of compiler errors.

Comment: then ask for help with that problem.  Or just read the code to see what the samples do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take reference for the code below.

TabbedPage1.xaml: I set the tab in bottom in xaml.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.TabbedPage1"
        xmlns:tabs="clr-namespace:App1"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        
        CurrentPageChanged="TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
     >
<!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->

<tabs:Page1 Title="Tab1">
    <Label x:Name="lbl01"></Label>
</tabs:Page1>
<tabs:Page2 Title="Tab2"/>
<tabs:Page3 Title="Tab3"/>
<tabs:Page4 Title="Tab4"/>
<tabs:Page5 Title="Tab5"/>
<tabs:Page6 Title="Tab6"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Code behind:

```
 public TabbedPage1(string parameter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbl01.Text = parameter;
    }
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPage1("Hello TabbedPage"));

    }
```

[image]

For mor information about passing data, you could refer to the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical